# generar excel en java y descargarlo desde jsp

Tags: java, mysql, excel

Lo que estoy asiendo es generando un archivo de Excel en java apartir de una consulta en sql el archivo se genera al presionar un boton de generar informe que hice en jsp
y la idea es que al momento de que se genera el Excel me aparezca la opción de descargar dicho archivo desde  el jsp por medio del servlet, la verdad es que no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre esto si me pueden explicar como hacerlo muchas gracias, por el momento lo que estoy asiendo es generando el Excel en una carpeta en el dico E: pero lo que necesito es que aparesca la opcion de descargarlo desde el jsp
adjunto la parte donde genero el Excel

```
  try {

            con = new Conexion();
            query = "SELECT  Nro_Documento,Nombres,Horas_registradas_en_jira,Proyecto,Horas_laboradas_sin_extras_y_sin_novedades FROM tbljira ORDER BY Proyecto";
            st = con.getConn().prepareStatement(query);

            res = st.executeQuery();

            while (res.next()) {
                TablaJira j = new TablaJira();
                j.setNro_Documento(res.getString("Nro_Documento"));
                j.setNombres(res.getString("Nombres"));
                j.setHoras_registradas_en_jira(res.getDouble("Horas_registradas_en_jira"));
                j.setProyecto(res.getString("proyecto"));
                j.setHoras_laboradas_sin_extras_sin_novedades(res.getDouble("Horas_laboradas_sin_extras_y_sin_novedades"));
                Jira.add(j);

            }

            for (int j = 0; j < Jira.size(); j++) {

                String ide = Jira.get(j).getNro_Documento();
                String name = Jira.get(j).getNombres();
                Double h = Jira.get(j).getHoras_registradas_en_jira();
                String proyec = Jira.get(j).getProyecto();
                Double time = Jira.get(j).getHoras_laboradas_sin_extras_sin_novedades();

                if (j == 0) {
                    idean = ide;
                    nombrean = name;
                    timea = h;
                    proan = proyec;
                    horat = time;

                } else if (ide.equals(idean) & proyec.equals(proan)) {

                    suma = suma + h;
                    idean = ide;
                    proan = proyec;
                    nombrean = name;

                    horat = time;
                } else {
                    det = new Detalle_Servicios();
                    if (suma == 0) {
                        total = timea / horat;
                        totalco = total * 100;
                        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(totalco);
                        bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

                        det.setPorcentaje_dedicacion(bd.doubleValue());
                        det.setHoras_laboradas_mes(horat);
                        det.setNombre_empleado(nombrean);
                        det.setNro_Documento(idean);
                        det.setHoras_dedicadas_Servicio(timea);
                        det.setNombre_proyecto(proan);
                        lst.add(det);

                        nombrean = name;
                        horat = time;
                        idean = ide;
                        proan = proyec;
                        timea = 0.0;
                        suma = h;

                    } else {
                        total = suma / horat;
                        totalco = total * 100;
                        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(totalco);
                        bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                        det.setPorcentaje_dedicacion(bd.doubleValue());
                        det.setHoras_laboradas_mes(horat);
                        det.setNombre_empleado(nombrean);
                        det.setNro_Documento(idean);
                        det.setHoras_dedicadas_Servicio(suma);
                        det.setNombre_proyecto(proan);
                        lst.add(det);

                        nombrean = name;
                        horat = time;
                        idean = ide;
                        proan = proyec;

                        suma = h;

                    }
                    if (j + 1 == Jira.size()) {
                        if (ide.equals(idean) & proyec.equals(proan)) {
                            det = new Detalle_Servicios();
                            total = suma / horat;
                            totalco = total * 100;
                            BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(totalco);
                            bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                            det.setNombre_proyecto(proan);
                            det.setPorcentaje_dedicacion(bd.doubleValue());
                            det.setHoras_laboradas_mes(horat);
                            det.setNombre_empleado(nombrean);
                            det.setNro_Documento(idean);
                            det.setHoras_dedicadas_Servicio(suma);

                            lst.add(det);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
            CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
            DataFormat forma = wb.createDataFormat();
            Font font = wb.createFont();
            font.setFontName("Arial");
            style.setFillForegroundColor((short) 30);
            style.setBottomBorderColor((short) 8);

            style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
            style.setVerticalAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
            style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            style.setWrapText(true);
            font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
            font.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
            style.setFont(font);

            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(1);
            XSSFCell cell;

            row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Nombre Empleado");
            row.getCell(1).setCellStyle(style);

            row.createCell(2).setCellValue("Proyecto");
            row.getCell(2).setCellStyle(style);

            row.createCell(3).setCellValue("Horas Dedicadas al servicios");
            row.getCell(3).setCellStyle(style);

            row.createCell(4).setCellValue("Horas laboradas");
            row.getCell(4).setCellStyle(style);

            row.createCell(5).setCellValue("Porcentaje de dedicacion");
            row.getCell(5).setCellStyle(style);

            int i = 2;
            for (int n = 0; n < lst.size(); n++) {
                nom = lst.get(n).getNombre_empleado();

                pro = lst.get(n).getNombre_proyecto();
                sum = lst.get(n).getHoras_dedicadas_Servicio();
                to = lst.get(n).getPorcentaje_dedicacion();
                horat = lst.get(n).getHoras_laboradas_mes();
                row = sheet.createRow(i++);
                cell = row.createCell(1);
                cell.setCellValue(nom);
                cell = row.createCell(2);
                cell.setCellValue(pro);
                cell = row.createCell(3);
                cell.setCellValue(sum);
                cell = row.createCell(4);
                cell.setCellValue(horat);
                cell = row.createCell(5);
                cell.setCellValue(to);

            }

            try {
                String ex = "ensayo";

                try (FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream("E:/copia/" + ex + ".xlsx")) {
                    wb.write(archivo);
                    archivo.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            Logger.getLogger(Detalle_ServiciosDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 opciones para esto, la forma configurada con un editor y la forma programativa:

1. Utilizar JasperReports, generando tu reporte con [JasperStudio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio), compilando el reporte (.jrxml) y agregandolo (.jasper) al classpath para luego exportarlo en el formato que desees (PDF, XLS, etc). [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746649/jasperreports-how-to-call-the-report-in-jsp-page)
2. Utilizar libreria POI para generarlo en forma programativa. [varios ejemplos](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html)

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226603/create-an-excel-file-for-users-to-download-using-apache-poi) un ejemplo de como streamearlo desde el servlet.

Suerte!!!